# Cannot connect to the Gmail API to run the quickstart guide

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, gmail-api

I'm trying to set up my email account to use the Gmail API, and just wanted to run the quickstart guide that Google has on its site, but I am getting this error:

```
0:289: execution error: File some object wasn’t found. (-43)
```

The code launches a web browser but it just takes me to a 400 page with this error:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error means that you have not appropriately registered your redirect URI in the API console. If you go to the API Console for the respective project, under APIs, you should see your Client IDs. Along with that should be a list of redirect URIs. If you do not see the correct redirect URI where you want the response returned to, just add it to the list.